# Only the first line is being printed on the GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Given C cars (number not given), input two strings, Make and Model, two integers, Year and Mileage for each car. (Using stringTokenizer to help input)

Store the C cars in a two different ArrayLists. One is sorted by Make, and the other isn't.

They will be printed at different ends of the GUI window.

**Problem:** All I can achieve at the moment is getting the very first line of the file to print onto the GUI. I tried messing with the location of the `leftSide.append(unsortedList.get(i).toString() + "\n");` and its right counterpart, but to no avail. I'm unsure if it's an issue with the readFile method, issues with implementing the JFrame, or an inefficient for-loop in charge of iterating through the appending of the arrayLists to the StringBuilders.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CarGUI extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea leftTextArea;
    private JTextArea rightTextArea;
    private StringBuilder leftSide;
    private StringBuilder rightSide;

    public static ArrayList<Car> unsortedList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    public static ArrayList<Car> sortedList = new ArrayList<Car>();

     public CarGUI() //default constructor for the GUI class
   {
        // Instance variables
       this("TITLE");
   }



     public CarGUI(String title) //the 1-argument parameter constructor 
        {
            // Call the super class constructor to initialize the super
            // class variables before initializing this class's variables
            super(title);

            // Configure the JFrame
            // Configure the JFrame components we inherited
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setSize(400, 400);
            this.setLocation(200, 200);


            this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2)); //1 row and 2 column
            this.leftSide = new StringBuilder("Unsorted Cars\n"); 
            this.rightSide = new StringBuilder("Sorted Cars\n");
            this.leftTextArea = new JTextArea(this.leftSide.toString());
            this.rightTextArea = new JTextArea(this.rightSide.toString());
            this.getContentPane().add(this.leftTextArea);
            this.getContentPane().add(this.rightTextArea);

            this.setVisible(true);
        }


public void readFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File myFile = new File("Cars.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String delimiter = ",";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiter);
    int tokenCount = new StringTokenizer(line, ",").countTokens(); //counts the tokens, should yield 4 
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){ 
        if(tokenCount != 4){ //if there isn't exactly 4 tokens, print the rest to the console
            System.out.println(tokenizer.toString());
        }
        else {
            //newCar(Make, Model, Year, Mileage);
            Car newCar = new Car(tokenizer.nextToken(), tokenizer.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
            unsortedList.add(newCar);
            sortedList.addAll(unsortedList);
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
    selectionSort(sortedList);
}



public void selectionSort(ArrayList<Car> sortedList2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList2.size(); i++) {
            int min = i;            
            for (int j = min + 1; j < sortedList2.size(); j++)
                if (sortedList2.get(j).getMake().compareTo(sortedList2.get(min).getMake()) < 0)
                    min = j;  
            Car temp1 = sortedList2.get(i);
            Car temp2 = sortedList2.get(i);
            Car notTemp = sortedList2.get(min);
            temp1 = notTemp; // sortedList2.get(i) = sortedList2.get(min);
            notTemp = temp2; // sortedList2.get(min) = sortedList2.get(i);
            //doing this because I need to set a variable on the left-hand side
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++){
            leftSide.append(unsortedList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
            rightSide.append(sortedList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
            }
         this.leftTextArea.setText(this.leftSide.toString());
         this.rightTextArea.setText(this.rightSide.toString());

    }   
}
```

The code is a bit messy and I only provided this class since the other classes are just simple main and Car classes. So it's 3 in total.

The car.txt file looks like

```
Subaru,Forester,2018,12902
Toyota,Camry,2016,24536
Nissan,Maxima,2009,45648
Honda,Civic,2002,98304
Subaru,Legacy,2014,2034
Hyundai,Kona,2012,27890
Toyota,Rav4,2013,6547
Honda,Accord
Honda,CR-V,2010,13904
Nissan,Altima,2012,45376
Honda,Pilot,2013,54398
Nissan,Leaf,2018,2300
Acura,MDX,2017,3892
```

Comment: Your code only prints the first line of output?

Comment: @FailingCoder Yeah, just the first Make, Model, Year, and Mileage.

Comment: Also, how are we supposed to know how many cars there are?

Comment: Are you printing your output with a loop? **Can we see what prints the messages?**

Comment: I guess that's why I made them into ArrayLists, so there isn't really a limit in how much they can take in.

Comment: @FailingCoder Yeah, I just updated the post. The output is at the bottom.

Comment: I am asking for **WHAT** outputs the output.

Comment: @FailingCoder Okay. that would be the for-loop at the end which appends the ArrayList contents into the string builder, which is then put into JTextAreas. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading file just for one line. The line reading code is not in your loop, and you close your scanner within your first iteration. Fix it like this.

```
public void readFile(String file) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File myFile = new File("Cars.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String delimiter = ",";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiter);
    int tokenCount = new StringTokenizer(line, ",").countTokens(); //counts the tokens, should yield 4 
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){ 
        if(tokenCount != 4){ //if there isn't exactly 4 tokens, print the rest to the console
            System.out.println(tokenizer.toString());
        }
        else {
            //newCar(Make, Model, Year, Mileage);
            Car newCar = new Car(tokenizer.nextToken(), tokenizer.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
            unsortedList.add(newCar);
            sortedList.addAll(unsortedList);
        }
        if(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiter);
            tokenCount = new StringTokenizer(line, ",").countTokens(); //counts the tokens, should yield 4 
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
    selectionSort(sortedList);
}
```

Comment: It's giving a bunch of errors.  at Cars.CarGUI.readFile(CarGUI.java:72) where "line = scanner.nextLine();" But I think you're right in that the readFile is the main issue.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at Cars.CarGUI.readFile(CarGUI.java:72)
 at Cars.Project1.main(Project1.java:11)

Comment: Yeah, Got it. There was no checking if next line exists for when the document end. Made edits. Check it now!

Comment: Okay, so now it's saying     at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at Cars.CarGUI.selectionSort(CarGUI.java:98)
 at Cars.CarGUI.readFile(CarGUI.java:79)
 at Cars.Project1.main(Project1.java:11). Which points to the for-loop and the selectionsort.

Comment: So, I tested it after fixing the for-loop, and it works way better now. It actually prints everything. So thanks for that, man! I just need to fix the selectionSort and I should be good to go. Only thing is the sorted side prints indefinitely.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)